# Connection is Failed with JSON stream parsing in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, web-services, ios6

I am trying to use simple Login using **JSON and Webservice**. The web service is blocked using Gateway username and password. What code is needed to include to pass the username and password to the gateway? Why is this happening? I get a Response code as 0 . Also if someone could provide a good tutorial to learn about web services and **JSON** in iOS. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code. Code is written in `UIButton`

```
            NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&Email=%@&Password=%@",
                [self.emailTextField text], [self.passwordTextfield text]];
            NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:/Gateway/api/json/reply/ZympayAuthenticateCustomer"];

            NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
            NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];

            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
            [request setURL:url];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
            [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
            [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
            [request setHTTPBody:postData];

            NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
            NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request 
                                                    returningResponse:&response error:&error];
            NSLog(@"Response code: %ld", (long)[response statusCode]);
            if ([response statusCode] >= 200 && [response statusCode] < 300) {
                NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData 
                                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);
                NSError *error = nil;
                NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                                                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                          error:&error];
                NSLog(@"Data: %@",jsonData);
                NSLog(@"Success: %ld",(long)success);

                if (success == 1) {
                    NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
                }
                else {                                
                    NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) jsonData[@"error_message"];
                   [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
                }
            } 
            else {
                //if (error) NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                [self alertStatus:@"Connection Failed" :@"Sign in Failed!" :0];
            }
        }
    }  
    @catch (NSException * e) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Exception: %@", e);
        [self alertStatus:@"Sign in Failed." :@"Error!" :0];
    }
    if (success)
    {
        NSLog(@"THIS IS SUCCESS");
        // [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login_success" sender:self];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you sending your content as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`? This is usually quite error prone, and you didn't pass the parameters correctly (omitting proper percent encoding). At any rate, use **JSON** as your content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

> NSURL *URL = [NSURL
>   URLWithString:@"http://www.site.com/test_json_link/?username='USERNAME'&password='PASSWORD'"];

Now, to prevent my web server from redirecting to the login page. I created a middleware to handle the above url. My custom middleware has this in it:

> ```
> if request.path != '/accounts/login/' and request.user.is_anonymous():
>      url = request.path.split('/')[1]
>      if url == 'test_json':
>          username = request.GET['username']
>          password = request.GET['password']
>          user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
>          if user is not None:
>              if user.is_active:
>                  login(request, user)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues in your code.

The single one which makes your approach quite likely to fail, is that you use 
`NSURLConnection` convenient class method `sendSynchronousRequest:`: If the request requires authentication, the credentials must be passed in the URL.

See also: [sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-BAJHAHGI)

Additionally, you have no way to cancel the request and take appropriate actions when the request is redirected.

So, the first big change in your approach would be to use `NSURLConnection`s delegate approach, or possibly use `NSURLSession` and `NSURLSessionTask`. There are quite a few solutions on SO which should give you a jump start to implement your own.

The recommended solution however, is to use a third party library.